# Codeigniter Routes.php within folder

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

I am using the latest version of CodeIgniter on Server2008 with IIS7.5

I have all of my CI files in a folder mywebsite.com/survey

```
nps = Controller
survey = Function
client_id = variable base64 encoded client number
```

I have a script that runs when you visit:
http://mywebsite.com/survey/nps/survey/client_id/MjgzOTcyMW

But I want for it to run when you visit:
http://mywebsite.com/survey/MjgzOTcyMW

How do I set up my routes.php?

I currently have:

```
$route['/:any'] = 'nps/survey/client_id/';
```

Comment: Try this `$route['(:any)'] = 'nps/survey/$1';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'nps/survey/client_id/$1';
```

or

```
$route['survey/(:any)'] = 'nps/survey/client_id/$1';
```

Answer (score 1):

*You have to make sure you don't mix up your routes here:*

Using just `$route['/:any']` would be wrong (even if you had the `(:any)` correct.
To properly define a route), remember that the *left hand side* is the pattern route, and the *right hand* (after the =) is the translated `controller/method/parameter` format.

So define the route (after all your other routes) as they are to be ordered from MOST specific to least specific (similar to ALLOW/DENY rules etc;):

```
$route['survey/(:any)'] = 'nps/survey/client_id/$1';
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining where I went wrong.  I am still new to the routes and this definitely helped a bunch.